# same script producing two different outputs with two different ways of execution in linux server

Tags: java, linux, cron

I had one script which has java class being called in this script.. but this script is giving two different outputs while executing in two different ways in linux machine

1st way is if i execute the script manually ./test.ksh  the java class is successfully executed and giving correct output

2nd way i am executing the script through cron job then it is giving java error `UnsupportedClassVersionError` for java class file

I had not made any changes to that java class but it is responding in two different ways

Comment: Looks like the 2nd way is not using the correct java version. Possibly because `cron` doesn't load some environment variable. Try and give `cron` the full path of the `java` command.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have two different Java Runtimes installed in this machine.

- A newer one is found in the PATH that the shell uses for your manual script.
- An older one is found from cron's environment.
- Your java class has been compiled with a compiler newer than the cron-found Java version, but not newer than the shell-found Java.

A Java class compiled with e.g. Java 11 can not be executed by e.g. a Java 8, but by a Java 11 and later.

Check the versions by executing `java -version` from the shell and from the cron job.

Comment: how can we check java version from cron?